# Generic minimum spanning tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, minimum-spanning-tree

I am reading myself about Minimum Spanning trees in Cormen,etc. Following is the
generic minimum spanning tree.

> Assume we have a connected, undirected graph G = (V, E) witha a weight
>   function w:E->R and we wish to find a minimum spanning tree for G.
>   Here we use greedy approach. This greedy strategy is captured by the
>   following "generic" algorithm, which grows the minimum spanning tree
>   one edge at a time. The algorithm manages a set of edges A,
>   maintaining the following loop invariant.
>
> Prior to each iteration, A is subset of some minimum spanning tree.

```
GENERIC-MST(G,w) 
A = NULL
while A is not a spanning tree 
  do find an edge (u, v) that is safe for A 
  A = A ∪ {(u, v)}
end while

return A
```

Questions

1. What does authore mean in invariant that "A" is subset of some minimum
   spanning tree?  What is "some" in this statement? i taught there is only one MST.
2. In above pseudocode what does author mean by "A is not a spanning tree"?
   i.e., how and when while loop exits?
3. In pseudo code where "some" minimum spanning tree, here my understading is only one.
   am i right?

Can any one pls explain with small example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** Absolutely not. MST are not necessarily unique. For example:

All edges are of equal weight.

```
u --- v
|     |
|     |
w --- x
```

The above graph has 4 MSTs, by removing any edge.

**2.** A spanning tree `T = (V,e)` in `G = (V,E)` is such that `|e| = |V|-1`

**3.** No.

Answer (score 1):

1. This is false. A graph may have many MST even if only two edges are equal.
2. **A** is not minimum spanning tree because of:

   2.1 First of all **A** is not a tree - it is disconnected.

   2.2 It does not span the graph

   The loop will exit when the above conditions are met
3. It is correct to say that it is in *some* MST as there are many.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are correct when you say a spanning tree of a graph is unique . But this is the case when all the edge lengths of the graph are different. As explained in the above answer, a graph with equal edge lengths can have many different spanning trees(all of them having the same total weight of course) .
2. The while loop exists when you have included all the vertices of the graph in your spanning tree . For this you add a check in your while loop .

Answer (score 0):

1. Incorrect as per @davin
2. The algorithm maintains the invariant that you have a forest, but the forest will not span the graph until you add enough edges.  Thus you have to keep adding edges until none of them are safe (at which point the loop breaks).
3. see 1.